# Get filtered data in reactable in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

I have a shiny application that lets the user filter data, eventually the user should be able to download the filtered data but I cannot access the filtered/shown data from reactable.

An MWE would be the following: (Note that the `getReactableState()` function does not return the filtered data but would work if one had to **select** all filtered data.)

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  reactableOutput("table"),
  verbatimTextOutput("table_state")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(iris, filterable = TRUE)
  })
  
  output$table_state <- renderPrint({
    print(getReactableState("table")) #< wrong code here...
    # the goal would be to get the rows which are currently shown here 
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Not an answer to the question but the package DT has inbuilt download button.

Comment: I would be able to get this working with DT, but due to some other functionality, Id prefer to use reactable throughout the app. Thanks for the comment though!

Answer (score 3):

Not a full answer, but at least it allows to download the filtered data as a CSV (solution from [here](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/javascript-api.html)):

```
tags$button("Download as CSV", onclick = "Reactable.downloadDataCSV('table')")
```

The full solution looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$button("Download as CSV", onclick = "Reactable.downloadDataCSV('table')"),
  reactableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(iris, filterable = TRUE)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: See also: https://github.com/glin/reactable/issues/104